# Swift UICollectionViewLayout, whither contentSize

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewlayout, contentsize

I'm converting my app from Obj-C to Swift.

I have this subclass of UICollectionViewLayout that overrides 'prepareForLayout' which has been renamed to 'prepare'.
So far so good.
However, in my obj-c code, I have this line:

```
self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(contentWidth, contentHeight+40);
```

where 'self' refers to the custom UICollectionViewLayout.

Now, in Swift, when I try to do

```
self.contentSize = CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight+40)
```

I get this error claiming

> Value of type 'myCustomCollectionLayout' has no member 'contentSize'

I do know that there is something like **collectionViewContentSize** but that doesn't seem to be appropriate here.

I hope any of you could advise me on how to proceed

Comment: If self is UICollectionViewLayout then your should try this         self.collectionView?.contentSize. Because collection view layout contains collectionView itself as property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*contentSize* is not *UICollectionViewLayout* property, it is property on *UICollectionView* or *UIScrollView*.

```
    collectionView?.contentSize = CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight+40)
```

But, why would you require this, in collectionview layout. You should really consider overriding the property collectionViewContentSize, which is exactly what contentSize does for UIScrollView,

```
override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight+40) 
}
```